# How to drop constant columns in pyspark, but not columns with nulls and one other value?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A similar question was asked and answered several times. For example here: [How to automatically drop constant columns in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786095/how-to-automatically-drop-constant-columns-in-pyspark)

But none of the answers, I found, address the problem, that `countDistinct()` doesn't consider null values as a distinct value. So a column with just two outcomes null and a none null value would be deleted as well.

One ugly solution would be to replace all null values in the spark dataframe with something you are sure doesn't exist elsewhere in the dataframe. But like I said that would be really ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add, to the `countDistinct`, an integer 0 or 1 which depends on whether there are nulls in the column:

```
# example dataframe
df.show()
+---+---+----+----+
|  a|  b|   c|   d|
+---+---+----+----+
|  1|  1|   1|null|
|  1|  2|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cnt = df.agg(*[
    (F.countDistinct(c) + F.max(F.col(c).isNull()).cast('int')).alias(c) 
    for c in df.columns
])

cnt.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  2|  1|
+---+---+---+---+

df.drop(*[c for c in cnt.first().asDict() if cnt.first()[c] == 1]).show()
+---+----+
|  b|   c|
+---+----+
|  1|   1|
|  2|null|
+---+----+
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats sounds very logical. Let me check this pretty quick, before I accept your answer.

Comment: to be honest i am not sure. I tried it on a "small" subset of my data and it didn't finish after serveral hours (3.5 million rows and 100 columns). I will try it on a even smaller subset later this day. Do you know if F.max(F.col(c).isNull()).cast('int') is particular slow?

Comment: I think `countDistinct` would be much slower, but there's not much that could be done to speed that up... It really needs to go through the whole dataset.

Comment: ok i tried a few things. I have a question first: should the `cast("int")` be inside the F.max function? I changed this and your code took 18 mins for 7000 rows and 92 colums on a normal cluster. In comparison `df.agg(*(countDistinct(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)).show()` took less than 10 sec. Isnt this strange? But i can confirm that your code does what it is itended for :)

Comment: it seems like that `cast("int`) outside of the `F.max()` function works as well. I gonna accept ypur answer, since it works. Would be still interested why it takes so long.

Comment: I think it works whether it's inside or outside the `max`. But I don't really understand why it took 100 times longer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230639/discussion-between-mirko-and-mck).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those column by checking their variance:

1. Creating a sample pyspark dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

simpleData = ((10, 1, 2),
              (10,2,2),
              (None, 1, 2)
             )
 
columns= ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.show()

#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|  10|   1|   2|
#|  10|   2|   2|
#|null|   1|   2|
#+----+----+----+
```

2. Finding the variance and force the variance to be greater than 0.

```
non_zero_var = df.select([F.variance(col) for col in df.columns]).collect()[0]
non_zero_var = [col for col_id, col in enumerate(df.columns) if non_zero_var[col_id] > 0]
non_zero_var

#['col2']
```

3. Finding the columns which has nulls but not fully null!

```
null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.isnan(c) | F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
few_null_cols = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if ((v > 0) and (v < df.count()))]
few_null_cols
# ['col1']
```

5. Select non-zero variance and non-fully-Null columns:

```
df.select(*few_null_cols, *non_zero_var).show()

#+----+----+
#|col1|col2|
#+----+----+
#|  10|   1|
#|  10|   2|
#|null|   1|
#+----+----+
```